# Storybook breaks existing Nextjs/React app's image loading

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, storybook

I am attempting to integrate Storybook into an existing NextJS/React app. It seems that when I simply run `npx sb init` for Storybook within the app, svg images no longer load in the original React app.  Upon inspection, these images have a `src="[object Module]"`. This seems to indicate to me that it's a webpack config issue where the svg loader configs from the original next.config.js is being overwritten by the Storybook webpack configs. Is there a way for me to either

1. force the Nextjs configs to supersede the Storybook webpack configs
   or
2. separate the webpack configs between Nextjs and Storybook?

Edit: Figured out that it was only svg images that were not loading, updated question to reflect that